# AngularDart Component dynamic templateUrl

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is it possible use specify templateUrls for a component dynamically? I'm not seeing anything in the @Component declaration that would allow me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-include in the component:

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'dynamictemplate',
    template: '<div ng-include="{{templateurl}}"></div>'
)
class DynamicTemplate {
  // ...
  String get templateurl => select?url1:url2;
}
```

Comment: So far I'm getting "Could not find asset <code>web&#x2F;templateUrl</code> in package <code>maui_frontend</code>." with that.

Comment: Aw shoot, I forgot the mustaches! Try again.

Comment: this is not very performatick, since it is resolved at javascript level

Comment: This does not work with Angular 2. Only with Angular 1.